# How to add an xml element in Java 1.4

Tags: java, jdk1.4

I am trying to add a "title" element but am getting a NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR error...

```
private static void saveDoc(String f) throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(f);

    // create DOMSource for source XML document
    DOMSource xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);

    Node nextNode = xmlSource.getNode().getFirstChild();

    while (nextNode != null) {
        System.out.print("\n node name: " + nextNode.getNodeName() + "\n");
        if (nextNode.getNodeName().equals("map")) {
            nextNode.appendChild(doc.createElement("title"));
```

**the line above is throwing error:**

> Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: `NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR`: An attempt is made to modify an object where modifications are not allowed.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source)
>       at myProject.Main.saveDoc(Main.java:171)
>       at myProject.Main.main(Main.java:48)

```
            break;
        }

        nextNode = nextNode.getNextSibling();             
    }
}
```

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?dctm xml_app="LOPackage"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "file:C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/joe/Desktop//LOPackage/map.dtd">
<map xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" class="- map/map " ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.1" domains="(map mapgroup-d) (topic indexing-d)">
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dctm://ai/0501869e80002504?DMS_OBJECT_SPEC=RELATION_ID" type="Le"/>
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dctm://ai/0501869e80002505?DMS_OBJECT_SPEC=RELATION_ID" type="Pr"/>
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dctm://ai/0501869e80002506?DMS_OBJECT_SPEC=RELATION_ID" type="Pr"/>
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's the reason, but check if your DOM implementation validates all the changes to the DOM. Because in you code,

```
nextNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("title"));
```

will attempt to create a text node as the child of `map` element and DITA Map doesn't allow that. Instead, try

```
Element title = doc.createElement("title");
title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("title content"))
nextNode.appendChild(title);
```

Comment: Good insight.  But I changed the code (and updated the question), same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the parent node seems to be read-only.
Clone the document by using:

```
Document newDoc = doc.cloneNode(true);
```

Set it to read-write by:

```
newDoc.setReadOnly(false,true);
//                       ^^^^ also sets children
```

Then do your stuff.
I would return the new document after saving it though.

Comment: neither Node nor Document has a setReadOnly property in 1.4.  Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the original document coming from?

That's the cause of the issue - the code that's reading in the document is constructing a read-only document. Without knowing how you're reading it in, it's pretty hard to work out how to change that.

I just did a quick test on Windows with JDK 1.4.2-11, and I can confirm that using the DocumentBuilderFactory (with the XML content coming from a Reader) does not create a read only Document.